# Table not showing up random values

Tags: php, arrays

Ok so first this is my code:

```
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;" width="400px;" height="400px;">

 <?php

    $table = range(1, 9);
    shuffle($table);

    for($i=0; $i<9; $i++){

        echo '<tr id="r'.$i.'">';

        for ($j=0; $j<9 ; $j++) { 
            echo '  <td id="r'.$i.'d'.$j.'">'.$table[$j].'</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>

</table>
```

All I want to do is, make a 9x9 square with unique values from 1-9 in each row and column. But when I run my code, it just shows random numbers for the columns and not rows. I want random numbers all over the block from 1-9.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Call `shuffle` inside the first `for` loop. You're only shuffling it once so you're just repeating the same row over and over:

```
 <?php

    $table = range(1, 9);

    for($i=0; $i<9; $i++){
        shuffle($table);
        echo '<tr id="r'.$i.'">';

        for ($j=0; $j<9 ; $j++) { 
            echo '  <td id="r'.$i.'d'.$j.'">'.$table[$j].'</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Damnit why couldn't I understand that stupid thing. D: Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Your array `$table` doesn't actually change inside the loop, and this is the problem. You need to run `shuffle($table)` inside the first loop (`for($i=0; $i<9; $i++)`).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is what you need or not

look at this code ..

```
    <table border="1" style="text-align:center;" width="400px;" height="400px;">

 <?php

    $table = range(1, 9);
    shuffle($table);

    for($i=0; $i<9; $i++){

        echo '<tr id="r'.$i.'">';
         shuffle($table);

        for ($j=0; $j<9 ; $j++) { 
            echo '  <td id="r'.$i.'d'.$j.'">'.$table[$j].'</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique values both in rows and columns take a look [at this link](http://www.mattlefevre.com/viewExample.php?tut=PHP&proj=Sudoku%20Generator).

You can use that code or re-use the generate function as below:

```
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;" width="400px;" height="400px;">
```

```
$grid = generate();
foreach ($grid as $i => $row){
    echo '<tr id="r'.$i.'">';
    foreach ($row as $j => $cell){
        echo '  <td id="r'.$i.'d'.$j.'">'. $cell .'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}



function generate() {
    $vGrid = $hGrid = array();
    $numbers = range(1,9);      
    for($x = 0; $x < 9; $x++) {
        for($y = 0; $y < 9; $y++) {
            $hGrid[$x] = !isset($hGrid[$x]) ? array() : $hGrid[$x];
            $vGrid[$y] = !isset($vGrid[$y]) ? array() : $vGrid[$y];
            $options = array_diff($numbers,$hGrid[$x],$vGrid[$y]);
            $key = array_rand($options);
            if(!isset($options[$key])) {
                return generate();
            }
            $val = $options[$key];
            $hGrid[$x][$y] = $vGrid[$y][$x] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $hGrid;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Shuffle the $table before inner loop

```
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;" width="400px;" height="400px;">
 <?php
    $table = range(1, 9);
    for($i=0; $i<9; $i++){
        echo '<tr id="r'.$i.'">';
        shuffle($table);
        for ($j=0; $j<9 ; $j++) { 
            echo '  <td id="r'.$i.'d'.$j.'">'.$table[$j].'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>
</table>
```